# Splitting rails routes into separate files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I've been tasked with breaking down a mammoth routes file on a legacy project. I've been looking at "[split route namespaces into different files](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/73-split-route-namespaces-into-different-files)" and it seems the best solution.

I am trying to include the paths in config/routes/*.rb by doing this at the top of the application.rb file:

```
config.paths.config.routes.concat Dir[Rails.root.join("config/routes/*.rb")]
```

but it gives an error:

```
/application.rb:23:in `<class:Application>': undefined method `config' for #<Rails::Paths::Root:0x007fa7475b48c0> (NoMethodError)
```

I tried changing the path to

```
config.routes.concat Dir[Rails.root.join("config/routes/*.rb")]
```

but it gives error 'method missing'.

Answer (score 0):

By requiring the file in routes.rb I can load it into the routes.

```
Gll::Application.routes.draw do
  require Rails.root.join('config/routes/public.rb')
end
```

Hope this helps someone